# Can only 100 refresh tokens be created per Google account?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api, google-oauth

According to Google, you can only create 100 refresh tokens per Google account and when you create more, the rest are canceled

> Currently, there is a limit of 100 refresh tokens per Google account for each OAuth 2.0 client ID. If the limit is reached, creating a new refresh token automatically invalidates the oldest refresh token without notice. This limit does not apply to service accounts.

In other words, logging in with Google to get customer data and also being able to use other APIs (eg Google Drive) thanks to the refresh token without having to request permissions again isn't useful?

It doesn't work when you plan to have more than 100k users and even more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This limit is per-user. You can have many thousands of users, but each user can only have at most 100 refresh tokens for this particular client ID.